# Black screen when resuming from suspend - xubuntu

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, suspend

I have a Thinkpad E495 with a AMD Ryzen 7 with integrated graphics.  I am using the default open source amdgpu driver and Xubuntu 18.04.4-LTS.  When I suspend in any way, e.g., via the menu or by setting up power manager to suspend when closing the laptop lid, it seems to suspend properly (i.e., the power light slowly blinks).  On resume (power button or opening the lid) however, the light on the power button goes solid, but the screen back light never turns on. The screen just stays dark.  I searched the forum and tried a number of suggestions (removing light-locker and using xscreensaver or xfce4-screensaver) and I haven't found anything that works yet.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried using  I ctrl-alt-f1 into text-console on resume and it does not open text-console.  It just seems locked up on a black screen with the "power light" on.

Comment: I attempted to do pm_tracing as per [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend)  I only found one dmesg "hash matches" line: 'code'[    0.869712]   Magic number: 0:408:740
[    0.869714]   hash matches /build/linux-xWiSio/linux-4.15.0/drivers/base/power/main.c:923

Comment: I have tried all of the following to suspend with the same results: Executing at a terminal pm-suspend; shutting the laptop, which is set to suspend on close; clicking the word Suspend in the GUI; and  having the computer suspend automatically on inactivity.  All have the same result on resume.  The power light goes from blinking to solid, but the screen remains black and no keyboard input has any effect - only a hard shutdown and reboot can be done.

Comment: I have tried switching to tty1 to see if I can kill light-locker or try anything else, but the system does not respond to any keyed input

Answer (score 0):

After much troubleshooting and very excellent support from ioria on the Ubuntu IRC Support, I was able to successfully resolve suspend/resume without locking up on resume by updating the kernel to the "hwe" kernel:

sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04

which installed the 5.3.0-28-generic kernel.
IRC Support also suggested using xscreensaver instead of light-locker, so I removed light-locker and installed xscreensaver.  It's uglier but apparently more stable.  There are detailed instructions for setting up xscreensaver for laptops using 18.04 LTS here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/9tlnnu/how_to_setup_xscreensaver_to_lock_on_suspend_for/

I had tried several different screensavers while troubleshooting, so within the XFCE Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart Tab referenced in the reddit instructions, I also unchecked Autostart for both light-locker and the other screensaver applications that were removed. I also had to apply the recommeneded "fix" from the reddit instructions in order to reliably lock the screen and require a password when closing the laptop lid.