# Laptop freezes after wake from suspend when not connected to power

Tags: suspend, freeze, wakeup

I'm a bit baffled about my computer's behavior with attempting to wake it from suspend when it is not connected to the power cable. When the laptop's lid is closed and it is suspended, and I want to carry it somewhere else and then open it, it freezes when opening the lid (the keyboard and power button light up, but black screen - only force shutdown and turning back on again solves this). It works just as it should (wake from suspend upon opening lid) when power is connected.

This is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS running on a Dell Precision 3530.

I've tried power settings, and updated to the "hwe" kernel as per [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209341/black-screen-when-resuming-from-suspend-xubuntu), but have not changed anything else.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing adding `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ldr"` in /etc/default/grub and updating GRUB as per:

https://www.dell.com/community/Precision-Mobile-Workstations/Precision-7540-will-only-boot-Linux-if-charger-is-connected/td-p/7449042